# get any module path in a npm monorepo

Tags: javascript, npm, monorepo

I have an NPM monorepo project (ESM):

```
<root>
|_package.json
|_node_modules/
| |_luxon (1.28.0)
|_packages/
  |_pack1
  | |_node_modules/
  | | |_luxon (3.0.1)
  | |_main.js
  |_pack2
    |_node_modules/
    |_main.js
```

Now, I need a way to get a module path from any of my `main.js` files:

For instance, given that `luxon` has 2 installed versions (in root, pack1), when I execute `main.js` from `pack1`, this what I'd like to get:

```
const luxonPath = (???)("luxon");
// luxonPath is <root>/packages/pack1/node_modules/luxon
```

From `pack2`:

```
const luxonPath = (???)("luxon"); 
// luxonPath is <root>/node_modules/luxon
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use require.resolve()

```
var luxonPath = require.resolve('luxon');

console.log("luxonPath is" + luxonPath);
```

Comment: Since, it's an ESM context I found the following: `import { createRequire } from "module"; const require = createRequire(import.meta.url); const pathName = require.resolve('luxon'); console.log(pathName);`

And its gives: `/home/guid/root/packages/pack1/node_modules/luxon/build/node/luxon.js`